# How do I control (PART) numbering in gitbook TOC?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

For a bookdown gitbook, without resorting to manual numbering how do I:

1. Disable `(PART)` numbering partially or entirely; or
2. For regular headings, enable 1st-level style numbering for 2nd-level headers while disabling it for 1st-level headers; or
3. Have independent numbering for 1st and 2nd level headers.

Any of these would work for me, but #3 would be ideal, and #1 is what I'm currently trying to get to work, using the special heading `(PART)` in bookdown as a workaround.

The structure I'd like to achieve is:

- Prologue

  - 1 Scene 1
- I Act 1

  - 2 Scene 2
- II Act 2

  - 3 Scene 3
- III Act 3

  - 4 Scene 4
- Epilogue

  - 5 Scene 5

Where at least scenes are automatically numbered. It seems intuitive to try this...

```
# (PART) Prologue {-}
# Scene 1
# (PART) Act I
# Scene 2
# (PART) Act II
# Scene 3
# (PART) Act III
# Scene 4
# (PART) Epilogue {-}
# Scene 5
```

...but [clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJrtY.png) that violates the current `(PART) {-}` syntax.

Counterintuitively `{-}` is necessary for the syntax but does not disable numbering like one might expect. So it seems my only option is this:

```
# (PART) Prologue {-}
# Scene 1
# (PART) Act I {-}
# Scene 2
# (PART) Act II {-}
# Scene 3
# (PART) Act III {-}
# Scene 4
# (PART) Epilogue {-}
# Scene 5
```

Which renders [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2NW4.png), with the Prologue and Epilogue numbered and messing up the numbering of the Acts.

So is it possible to control `(PART)` numbering?

```
>devtools::session_info('bookdown')

Session info ------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           

Packages (selected) ----------------------------------------
 bookdown    0.3     2016-11-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 knitr       1.15.1  2016-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rmarkdown   1.3     2016-12-21 CRAN (R 3.3.2)

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.17.2’
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/356

Comment: Repo with permutations of heading options that almost but don't quite work: https://github.com/brooksambrose/bookdown-partnumbering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [added](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/e2476b2143692af315f7c42895d04bd9f94ab609) support for unnumbered parts in [**bookdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) (>= v0.3.19). The syntax is `# (PART\*)`.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks so much for this and everything else you've done for the community :)